# XPath expression - translate to lowercase

Tags: xml, xpath, translate

I have the following XPath expression:

```
"//*[@name='outputFormat']/ows:Value"
```

I would like to make it case insensitive, as in some XML files outputFormat may also be OutputFormat etc. I know the `translate` function in XPath 1.0 and would like to apply it for this expression. My simple question is: how? I tried with this:

```
"//*[@Translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='outputformat']/ows:Value"
```

but this throws an error.
Any help (including tips what is the best way to handle this kind of problems in XPath) would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm using XPath from VB.NET, the error is 'Element "//*Translate..." has a wrong / incorrect token' (translated by myself, original English may be a bit different).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `@` should be attached to `name` since it's the attribute you're matching, while `translate()` is a function. Try this:

```
"//*[translate(@name, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'outputFormat']/ows:Value"
```